# Functional derivative of integral of minimum

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Given two sufficiently regular functions $u,v$ on a domain $\Omega$ and a functional $F[u] := \int_\Omega \min(u,0)dx$.

Now I want to determine the functional derivative of $F$.
Therefore

$DF[u]v = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\big|_{\epsilon = 0} \int_\Omega \min(u+\epsilon v,0)dx$.

My result would be 
$DF[u|v = \int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_{u<0}vdx$.

Is this the correct solution ? I'm a bit insecure about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is only true if the measure of $\{ x \in \Omega \mid u(x) = 0\}$ is zero.

Comment: Sorry made a typo. $DF[u]v = \int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_{u\le 0}vdx$. Would that be correct ?

Comment: No, if the measure of $\{u = 0\}$ is positive, $F$ is not differentiable at $u$.